# can I switch PDA operating system from Windows CE 5 to Windows mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

I have a Motorola MC3000 barcode scanner handheld.  I want to run an app that is only compatible with Windows Mobile operating sytem, but my MC3000 PDA runs Windows CE 5. Please avise if/how I can reinstal the operating sytem on my MC3000 PDA.
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to do it.
The product [specification](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers/MC3000_Brick_US-EN?vgnextoid=0cfe3acf35e95110VgnVCM1000008406b00aRCRD) says that it supports WIndows Mobile 6.1.
Although i would recommend that you call up Motorola  Customer Support and get help from them to avoid any issues.